# Is there a function to test if a number is rational in Z3?

Tags: z3

When working with real numbers in Z3, rational numbers are automatically depicted as fractions. This means Z3 has a mechanism to test whether a number is rational or not (in order to decide on how to depict it), right?

Is this mechanism accessible via a concrete function in Z3? I know it's possible to write such a function myself, but if Z3 can already do this by itself that'd be unnecessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two functions in the API that'll help you with this:

- [is_rational_value](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a20f6da8821eb04f02259c0eb4ed97da3)
- [is_algebraic_value](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#ac0fed16ee6f4a41be049399ec5dfb35c)

The above are in the Python API, but you can find similar functions in other API's from C/C++/Java etc. I don't think these are available if you restrict yourself to the SMTLib interface only.

Note that these'll work correctly if based on static checks and only when you have a fully determined value. For instance:

```py
>>> is_rational_value(Real('x'))
False
```

though of course `x` can be bound to a rational value later on depending on all the other constraints you add on it. To wit:

```py
>>> x = Real('x')
>>> is_rational_value(x)
False
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(x == 1)
>>> s.check()
sat
>>> m = s.model()
>>> m[x]
1
>>> is_rational_value(m[x])
True
>>> is_algebraic_value(m[x])
False
```

Compare this to:

```py
>>> y = Real('y')
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(y * y == 2)
>>> s.check()
sat
>>> m = s.model()
>>> m[y]
-1.4142135623?
>>> is_rational_value(m[y])
False
>>> is_algebraic_value(m[y])
True
```